# Missing dependency after updating intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm so close to giving up. I've had so many issues with compatibility recently - just utterly ridiculous how fragile applications are. In fixing an issue I had with `type errors` by updating to `IntelliJ 2019.1.2 CE`. Upon trying to compile the project I get:

```
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\Users\sambo\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.6\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/package
.class)
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\Users\sambo\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.6\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/runtime
/package.class)
error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:99)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:102)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:264)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:264)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnyRefClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:263)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnyRefClass(Definitions.scala:263)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.specialPolyClass(Definitions.scala:1120)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RepeatedParamClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:407)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RepeatedParamClass(Definitions.scala:407)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1154)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1152)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1196)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1196)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1261)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.doCompile(Main.scala:79)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:54)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main.process(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at sbt.compiler.RawCompiler.apply(RawCompiler.scala:33)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:159)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:358)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:152)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:358)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:152)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:121)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:118)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:358)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(ComponentCompiler.scala:118)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:118)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:118)
        at sbt.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:31)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:116)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:111)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:358)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler.sbt$compiler$IvyComponentCompiler$$compileAndInstall(ComponentCompiler.scala:111)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(ComponentCompiler.scala:102)
        at sbt.IfMissing$Define.apply(ComponentManager.scala:75)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$createAndCache$1(ComponentManager.scala:39)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:27)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:26)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.lockGlobalCache(ComponentManager.scala:49)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1(ComponentManager.scala:25)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$getOrElse$1(ComponentManager.scala:32)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
        at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ComponentManager.scala:47)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.files(ComponentManager.scala:44)
        at sbt.ComponentManager.file(ComponentManager.scala:53)
        at sbt.compiler.IvyComponentCompiler.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:102)
        at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler$$anon$2.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:35)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:118)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:128)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:104)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:62)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:57)
        at sbt.compiler.CompilerCache$$anon$2.apply(CompilerCache.scala:47)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:45)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:74)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:49)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:32)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:72)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:71)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:99)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:71)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:155)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:141)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:886)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:877)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:875)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This is my build:

```
  Seq(
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % Test,
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194",
    "org.webjars" % "metisMenu" % "1.1.3",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.16.6-play26",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo-akkastream" % "0.16.6",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "bootstrap-sass" % "3.3.6",
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.4",
    "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.7.0",
    "org.webjars" % "datatables" % "1.10.5",
    "org.webjars" % "datatables-plugins" % "1.10.5"
  )
```

I'm using `JDK 1.8 / scala 2.12.2 / play: 2.6.2 / sbt: 0.13.15`. My `%JAVA_HOME` is routed to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`. I've not changed anything else so naturally I'm losing it right now. Any help is welcome to stop the machines winning.

Answer (score 0):

For me these things usually do the trick:

1. Just Restart Intellij

or

2. Delete `.idea`

   - close Project
   - delete `.idea` from the Project
   - open the project again in Intellij, make sure it is recognised as SBT project.

Comment: Thanks. I have since got this working but only by reverting back to the previous version of `IntelliJ`. I think that `IntelliJ CE 2019.2.1` does not like `sbt version 0.13.15` so was bullying me into upgrading to `0.13.18` but this was causing the dreaded chain version conflict for other plugins/imported libraries. So I was forced to install the previous version for now. For others; you may want to explain how - on your point of `open the project again in Intellij, make sure it is recognised as SBT project.`

Comment: To disable the automatic version upgrade, you may untick the "allow overriding sbt version" in the sbt options for your project. Usually 0.13.18 should be compatible with 0.13.15. Do you know where it caused a conflict?