# ClassNot found exception in helloworld program in scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and scala and I am writing a helloworld program in sbt. But I am getting below error message :

[image: error stack]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwL9Y.png)

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476693/2750966

Comment: I did the above step but now the following error came:                              Error:scalac: Multiple 'scala-library*.jar' files (scala-library-2.13.0.jar, scala-library-2.13.0.jar) in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK sbt: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0:jar                                                                                            Even I delete the additional jar in libraries same problem exists

Comment: have you added a jdk and a scala sdk to your project? try also `sbt compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have defined a JDK and Scala SDK in your *Module Settings* (`F4`)

[image: Module Settings]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfmVH.png)

Can you tell me what I am missing here

Comment: scala-reflect jars are not showing in standard library classes and when I tried to add from directory reflect folder has (jar://C:/Users/sachin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.13.0.jar!/scala/reflect) has macros folder with internal in it but I am not able to add it.

Comment: what was the output of `sbt compile`?

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Comment: I added my reflect libraries in standard libraries and the code worked . Thanks